# Processing multi-band raster in qgis using python script?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-2.18, band

Is there a way to process (for example by using raster calculator or r.null) a multi-band raster?

When I try to use raster calculator in QGIS 2.18.3 on multi-band raster the output is a raster that contains only the first band, and I would like to get a raster with the same number of bands as the input.

I would like to multiple every band by 5. When I use raster calculator the output is a single-band raster (just the first band) multiple by 5.
Another thing I'm try to do is to change all "0" value to null for every band. SAGA mosaic tool is able to set null but it doesn't work on multiband raster, and GDAL mosaic doesn't have that option. When I use the "r.null" tool it only sets null values to the first band, which is the output.

It would be great if you can help me using python script.

Comment: Please, can you edit your question with an example of what you inserted as expression into the raster calculator?